# Customizing a Line Chart to show gaps when data is missing

Tags: charts, linechart, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a scenario that calls for me to edit a line chart that gets values every day and reports on them.

If you can help then please show me what I can do to make this possible?

Example:

I get data every day, which is a value for Mon-Sun. In an example let's use this as the values:

Mon: 15, Tue: 20, Wed: 45, Thurs: 50, Fri: 15, Sat: 20, Sun: 28 
The chart for this would show the movement from each value to the next as it should.

[image: Chart with No Zero Values]

Now I have a situation where there could be a 0 as a value for any of the given days. I however do not want to reflect the zero by having the graph dip to 0 and then rise to the next value. I need the graph to not draw a line for the 0 entry, so basically any days that have a 0 will be seen by gaps between the next value.

[image: Chart with Zero Values]

Can anyone help? If I need to explain myself better then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to modify the source query so that anywhere in the dataset you have a 0, you replace with a null value. This way reporting services will automatically display the report exactly how you are wanting.

Example, for MS SQL datasource:

SELECT case when myCol = 0 then null else myCol end as myCol FROM myTable